# Composer Paysafe any version?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, paysafe

First time I try to add a package in the composer.json of my laravel application.

I trying to add this package paysafe https://github.com/paysafegroup/paysafe_sdk_php

I downloaded the repo and moved it under the folder "vendor" in laravel

It seem that I need to specific the version of the package I am trying to install , but I don't have this information ...

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.4.*",
        "mailgun/mailgun-php": "~1.7.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0",
        "mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf": "^2.0",
        "paysafe":"*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

When I run this command

```
php composer.phar require paysafe
```

I get this error message:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                
  Could not find package paysafe at any version for your minimum-stability (dev). Check the package spelli  
  ng or your minimum-stability
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have recently updated the SDK which should have fixed the version conflict issue. Please use PHP SDK version 1.0.1 and give it another shot!

All the best!